# Replace nth occurence of text in MS-Word document using C#

Tags: c#, text, ms-word, replace

Is there a way to replace the nth (given occurrence) of a text in MS Word document using C#'s

`Application.Selection.Find.Execute` Method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, that method alone cannot accomplish your goal as it only allows *all*, *none*, or *first* replacement.  But the API suite is total is **more** than powerful enough to do what you want to do, you just have to fiddle with it until you find the right API calls to get what you want.

Here are some important documents:

- [Working with Text in Documents](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386277.aspx)
- [How to: Search for Text in Documents](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f1f367bx.aspx)
- [How to: Loop Through Found Items in Documents](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e7d13z59.aspx)

The first link is the overview.  In particular, you need to combine the calls in the second two to do what you want: loop using a search, stop and do a replace and the selected text at your desired occurrence.  Using a new complex API can be difficult but use the examples and search for API methods for similar code to get ideas.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer. It works fine. The third link helped me most in the task...